# how to use a bower package in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bower

I installed bower from NPM and then i installed a bower package Crypto-js.

Is it possible to use this package in my node js code by simply writing require

Like this

```
var crypt= require('./package path/md5');
var hash= crypt.MD5('Message');
console.log(hash.toString(crypt.enc.Base64));
```

Here my point is not about only this library, i want to ask if this is the way to use bower package in nodejs or is there any other way to use bower package in nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bower is for front-end and it is not exported for node.js

you should use npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js instead

Answer (score 0):

There are two things

- bower is *package for web* build by twitter
- and as you already aware that nodejs is server side

So you can't use bower in nodejs server-side application.

And even if you use bower in front end, it's done by using *script* tags.

for more refer [this blog](https://www.codementor.io/bower/tutorial/beginner-tutorial-getting-started-bower-package-manager)